# Python selenium browser firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Would like some help with why this isn't working

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cycli/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 3221225595
```

Comment: Have you installed geckodriver.exe? Is your PATH environment variable configured to the location of geckodriver.exe?

Comment: Yep geckodriver.exe is on my desktop and I have created a path to the desktop

Comment: I don't see any path to geckodriver.exe in the code you provided.

Comment: I went to Control Panel\System and Security\System then advanced system settings then environment variables and added a path

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What version of FF vs. geckodriver are you running?

Comment: I got this from gecko https://imgur.com/Rlx4TGZ

Comment: geckodriver 0.25 and 59.0.2 ff

Comment: You should update firefox.  v59 is very old: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_version_history

Answer (score 1):

Download geckodriver for Firefox from the below link,

```
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
```

The geckodriver has to be in the code path or the path to it has to be specified.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
#Setting up FireFox Driver Options
driver_options = Options()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#driver_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
                firefox_profile=profile, 
                options=driver_options,
                executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
```

Comment: I have it and it's specified

Comment: Did you specify the way i have mentioned in the answer

Comment: ```from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
#Setting up FireFox Driver Options
driver_options = Options()
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#driver_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
                firefox_profile=profile, 
                options=driver_options,
                executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
```

Comment: executable_path="c:/Users/{ur_username}/Desktop/geckodriver.exe". since u have placed ur geckodriver in ur desktop

Comment: did you download the correct version of geckodriver for the PC. also try placing the geckodriver in the path where your python file is

Comment: Yep and both geckodriver and python file are on the desktop

Comment: it should work, else u are making some blunder mistake along the way

Comment: gecko can't run on its own. its called through selenium package. executable_path="geckodriver.exe" and place the fle in the python code path.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
executable_path="C:\Users\cycli\Desktop\geckodriver.exe"

Comment: have u placed ur geckodriver.exe in ur Desktop

Comment: dont keep it under any folder. just the file in ur desktop

Comment: It's not in any folder it's just on the desktop

Comment: https://imgur.com/ZQp7yYE
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
executable_path="C:\Users\cycli\Desktop\geckodriver.exe"

Comment: not this one. I mean the error u get when u run python code

Comment: that's all I get

Comment: and a red box around the 2nd =

Comment: did the download the correct bit version of geckodriver and is it from this link https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Yes I did do that

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200364/discussion-on-answer-by-sudharsana-rajasekaran-python-selenium-browser-firefox).

Answer (score 1):

**Final block of code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

[More](http://allselenium.info/how-to-open-given-url-in-firefox-browser/)